# Using python, how do I copying data from one spreadsheet to another if the ID matches

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I have two Excel spreadsheets, in the first one I have a column with ID numbers, but they are not unique (there are multiple rows with same ID). There are also blank columns (Field4 and Field5).

In the second file I have data where the IDs are unique (not repeated) in the first column and then the Field 4 and Field 5 data.

This is what I want to do:

1. Loop/iterate over each row in File1.
2. Get the ID from the first column
3. Then go to the File2 row corresponding to that ID.
4. Copy the corresponding Field4 and Field5 from File2
5. Paste that back into the originating row from File 1 to fill out the Field4 and Field5 columns.

Hopefully that makes sense! Python/openpyxl/pandas would be preferred. Or even just the breakdown of the "steps" into programming concept would be much appreciated.

[image: File1.xlsx]
[image: File2.xlsx]

I've tried using openpyxl/pandas but getting stuck on how to access/iterate to get the data and also copy and store the column data if needed (dictionary/list, etc.)

Comment: What have you tried?  Show us the code you have, and point out what is not working.  This is not a code-writing service.  Are you guaranteed the two have the same number of lines?  If so, then this is not very hard.

Comment: You're right, I should have posted my code. I'm quite new to this and it was just scattered and not-working so I felt like it would make it more complicated to troubleshoot.  I had been trying to use:   `for index,row in df.iterrows():` to loop through the df and get the IDs. Then using `if ID not in dict:` then creating a `dict[ID] = {}` and then assigning the sub-element fields....essentially nested dictionaries. But thinking I need to go back and read up more on fundamentals. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) then use [`ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) with an `openpyxl` engine to update the first ss.

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.cell import coordinate_to_tuple
from openpyxl.styles import numbers

df1 = pd.read_excel("file1.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1")
df2 = pd.read_excel("file2.xlsx", sheet_name="Sheet1")

target_cols = ["Field4", "Field5"]
srow, scol = coordinate_to_tuple("E2") # <- change the starting cell here

out = pd.merge(df1.drop(columns=target_cols), df2, on="ID", how="left")[df1.columns]

with pd.ExcelWriter("file1.xlsx", engine="openpyxl",
                    mode="a", if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer:
    out[target_cols].to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name="Sheet1", 
                              startrow=srow-1, startcol=scol-1, header=None)
    for cell in writer.sheets["Sheet1"]["F"]:
        cell.number_format = numbers.FORMAT_CURRENCY_USD
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton! This does produce the correct output. I didn't know about the `merge` or `Excel.Writer` lots to work on from here! Appreciate your guidance on this.